# Why does Jojo's Bizarre Adventure have so many English references?

Tags: japanese-language, jojos-bizarre-adventure

In the sub-titled version of Jojo's Bizarre Adventure, there are many points in the story where one of the character's repeatedly uses an English phrase.

Examples include Mr. JoeStar saying "Holy Shit" or the Genie stand saying "Hail 2 U". Many of these phrases are not even normal English saying like "Hail 2 U". Why is it that these English phrases are included, and why are they often strange to a native English speaker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon this is primarily because JoJo starts based in 1880s Britain and they wanted to keep referencing this aspect of JoJo's heritage. Even down the generation line when they are based in America, Jojo still has a very english-based family tree.

As for why some of them are not common in actual English conversation, It's more than likely problems with translating from English to Japanese and back again.

Comment: Agreed, that makes sense. I actually quite like the oddity of their translations it makes it more bizarre ^_^

Comment: Yeah I think it's nice in a weird sort of way

Comment: Araki is a huge Anglophile too. He loves western culture, and especially its music.